# Keep Wave Modifier inside an Object?

Tags: animation, modifiers, collision

Whats the best way to keep a Wave Modifier inside an Object? I have a Goblet here with the Wave Modifier applied to the liquid inside, however I only want the liquid surface moving and not the rest of the liquid outside the goblet. (See Pic)

[image]

I've tried Collision for both the liquid and goblet, and converting the Wave Modifier to Liquid, no results so far. Attached are the current Wave Modifier Settings.

[image]

Comment: Create a vertex group for the top of the liquid surface and use the vertex group for your wave motion.

Comment: Got it, Thank you!